# passing signals from linux driver to user application

Tags: linux

My question is regarding the use of send_sig_info and sigaction functions in order to pass signal from driver to user application for signalling an interrupt. Currently my code is as below:

```
//in driver's interrupt handler function
ret = send_sig_info(SIGNAL_NUMBER, &info, t); 

//in user application
struct sigaction sig;
sig.sa_sigaction = read_proc;
sig.sa_flags     = SA_SIGINFO;
sigaction(SIGNAL_NUMBER, &sig, NULL);
```

where read_proc is the handler function from user application. I am now trying to modify the code so that incase of multiple interrupts a different signal number will be sent to user application so that its corresponding handler will be called as below:

```
//in driver handler 1
info.si_int   =info.si_int+1;
//set the appropriate signal number
info.si_signo = SIGNAL_NUMBER;
ret = send_sig_info(SIGNAL_NUMBER, &info, t); 

//in drivers handler 2
info.si_int   =info.si_int+1;
//set the appropriate signal number
info.si_signo = SIGNAL_NUMBER2;
ret = send_sig_info(SIGNAL_NUMBER2, &info, t);
```

and on the user application side

```
struct sigaction sig;
sig.sa_sigaction = read_proc;
sig.sa_flags     = SA_SIGINFO;
sigaction(SIGNAL_NUMBER, &sig, NULL);

//sigaction for other buffers
struct sigaction sig2;
sig.sa_sigaction = read_proc2;
sig.sa_flags     = SA_SIGINFO;
sigaction(SIGNAL_NUMBER2, &sig2, NULL);
```

however in this case the function read_proc2 is not called. Can anyone suggest the proper solution so that a different function will be called on the user app side according to the different si_signo?

Regards,